# Error: Unable to resolve module `react` from `index.js`: react could not be found within the project

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

### Error: Unable to resolve module `react` from `index.js`: react could not be found within the project.

When i tried to run my project then it will give me this bundling failed error.

[image]

Here is my index.js file code.

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import src from './Screens/Search'
import AppContainer from "./Component/MainNavigation";
class myApp extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <AppContainer />
        )
    }

}
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => myApp);
```

package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "CharityDating",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-draggable": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-draggable-grid": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-pulse": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sortable-grid": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-switch-toggle": "^1.1.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.13",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
    "react-toggle": "^4.1.1",
    "responsive-image": "^0.3.1",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your ```package.json``` ?

Comment: Yes i can post package,json file @mindmaster

Comment: you can add react manually using yarn add react and try again

Comment: Try to install the last version of ```react``` which is ```16.12.0```. And then follow the steps from @prakash-karena post.

Comment: In my case, I had `from "React"` instead of `from "react"`. I guess at React 16.9+, it became case sensitive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I installed react again once more.Using 'npm i react' and error is solved.

Answer (score 6):

This error is might be related to npm installation try this out :

**Solution 1** : `follow the steps given with your error to resolve this error`

**Solution 2 :**

```
npm start -- --reset-cache

then

react-native run-android // in separate command line
```

**Solution 3 :**

```
  Delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file 

  => npm install
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Comment: I did it .But there is same issue.

Comment: have you intalled your all packages in root directory ?? npm install

Comment: Yes.But i will check it again.@Prakash Karena

Answer (score 3):

Just went through the same error after adding typescript.
I solved it by adding `json` extension to **resolver** in `metro.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs', 'json'],
      }
}
```